# Why are inflammations painful in the case of a tendinitis?

Tags: tendinitis

When suffering from tendinitis, does the inflammation itself cause any pain, and if so why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Why are inflammations painful in the case of a tendinitis?**
>
> When suffering from tendinitis, does the inflammation itself cause any
>   pain, and if so why?

Based on the [definition of tendinitis](http://patient.info/health/tendonitis-and-tenosynovitis) actually meaning **inflammation of a tendon**, what's typically associated with this condition, and the body's immune system response with it stimulating nerve cells and triggering pain, **inflammation can and does cause pain**.

> [**Definition <sub>(1)</sub>**](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/tendinitis/basics/definition/con-20020309)
>
> Tendinitis is inflammation or irritation of a tendon — any one of the
>   thick fibrous cords that attaches muscle to bone. The condition causes
>   pain and tenderness just outside a joint. <sub>(1)</sub>

When swelling occurs and the immune system responds accordingly, this process can also stimulate nerves and trigger the pain effect so based on this, that is WHY inflammation causes pain with tendinitis or any other condition for this matter with the human body.

> [**WebMD - Inflammation <sub>(2)</sub>**](http://www.webmd.com/arthritis/about-inflammation)
>
> When inflammation occurs, chemicals from the body's white blood cells
>   are released into the blood or affected tissues to protect your body
>   from foreign substances. This release of chemicals increases the blood
>   flow to the area of injury or infection, and may result in redness and
>   warmth. Some of the chemicals cause a leak of fluid into the tissues,
>   resulting in swelling. This protective process may stimulate nerves
>   and cause pain. <sub>(2)</sub>

---

- [**Mayo Clinic - Tendinitis Definition(1)**](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/tendinitis/basics/definition/con-20020309)

  - [Meet the Mayo Clinic Staff](http://www.mayoclinic.org/about-this-site/meet-our-medical-editors)
- [**WebMD - Inflammation (2)**](http://www.webmd.com/arthritis/about-inflammation)

  - [Meet the WebMD Staff](http://www.webmd.com/about-webmd-policies/about-who-we-are)